# In the function $f(x) = \min\{\tan(x),\cot(x)\}$, is $f$ defined at $x = 0$ or $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: functions

In the function $f(x) = \min\{\tan(x),\cot(x)\}$, is $f$ defined at $x = 0$ or $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$? $\tan(x)$ is defined at $x = 0$ while $\cot(x)$ is not. At $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\tan(x)$ is not define while $\cot(x)$ is.

If one function is defined but the other isn't, is the minimum function defined?

Comment: No, it is not .

Comment: Not only is the function not defined at those points according to this definition, you cannot even "fill in" those points with values that will make the function continuous. On one side of such a point the limit is $0$, on the other side the limit is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to the expression $f(x) := \min\{\tan(x),\cot(x)\}$ be well defined, its argument must be well defined. In the present case, the arguments are given by $\tan(x)$ and $\cot(x)$. More precisely, both expressions are defined based on the more elementary functions $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$:
\begin{align*}
\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \cot(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}
\end{align*}

Since division by zero is not allowed, we must exclude the cases where $\cos(x) = 0$ and $\sin(x) = 0$.

The first case happens for the following values of $x$:
\begin{align*}
\cos(x) = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow \cos(x) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi\right)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(x = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi\right)\wedge(k\in\mathbb{Z})
\end{align*}

The second case happens for the following values of $x$:
\begin{align*}
\sin(x) = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow \sin(x) = \sin(k\pi)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x = k\pi)\wedge(k\in\mathbb{Z})
\end{align*}

Hence the original expression makes sense iff
\begin{align*}
x\not\in\left\{z\in\mathbb{R} : \left(z = \frac{k\pi}{2}\right)\wedge(k\in\mathbb{Z}) \right\}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!